# how to save data in Prefrences when change between viewpager in Android

Tags: android, android-viewpager, sharedpreferences, viewpagerindicator

I use ViewpagerIndicatator for using viewpager in my application. I have three Fragment and when I switch between pages, must be save data in shared Preferences, then  uses onStop(),onPause() and onDestory() lifecycle  but not work.

my code:

```
public class BirthFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.e("Test", "hello");
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        init_Cal();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_user_layout, container,
            false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        Prefrences_User = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("user", 0);
        editor_user = Prefrences_User.edit();
        editor_user.putString("username", "user");
        editor_user.putString("birth", "");
        editor_user.commit();
    }
}
```

and viewpagerActiivty:

```
public class ViewPagerExample extends FragmentActivity {

    private MyAdapter mAdapter;
    private ViewPager mPager;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        mAdapter = new MyAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }

    public static class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 3;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return new BirthFragment();
            case 1:
                return new PeriodFragment(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            case 2:
                return new FinalFragment();
            default:
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and Now How to save data when switch between another fragment?

Answer (score 1):

how about you implement a `OnPageChangeListener` and when the page change it will call the following function

```
@Override
public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

then add your `sharedpreferences` code in to the suitable function so when the scroll is finished it will save in `sharedpreferences`.

Don't forget to register the pager to the listener..

```
yourPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
```

**Update**

first implement the `onPageChangeListener` in your `ViewPagerExample`  class.

then under `mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);` add the following:

```
mPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
```

create a function in your fragment that and add the sharedpreferences code to that function.

back to your ViewPageExample and within `onPageScrolled(int position, float arg1, int x)`

```
@Override
public void onPageScrolled(int position, float arg1, int x) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Fragment f = (Fragment) mPager.getAdapter().instantiateItem(mPager, position);
    if(position == 0 && x > 0 ) {


        //birth.newInstance(ViewPagerExample.this);
        ((BirthFragment)f).SaveData(MainActivity.this);
    }

}
```

a better practice is to use interfaces to communicate between main and fragment rather than calling the function directly

now if you want to save the data in page 0 then if(position == 1) save to sharedPreferences if you want to save the data of page 1 then if(position == 2) save to sharedPreferences.
however if you are at page 3 you can't save data because there are no more transactions.

hope you got the idea, then you can manipulate it according to your code.

Comment: thanks,i have three fragment BirthFrgment,PeriodFragment and FinalFragment.How to Recognize scroll ?

Comment: in sharePrefrences set data in EditText.and Now we save data in viewoagerExample.how to save data from editText on BirthFragment?

Comment: create a function in fragment that you want to save your data.. then in if(position == 1) create an instance of fragment and call the saving function.. I am sorry I am all over the place, but because I am in the work currently and the boss is roaming around..

Comment: when I use this code  editor_user.putString("username", edt_name.getText().toString());// its error becase oncreateview not started in fragment

Comment: can you tell me the following?
1) the fragment position.
2) the pager position.
3) and where are u going.

or update your code... now the thing is fragmentPagerAdapter keeps the current fragment with the previous fragment and next fragment alive so the onCreateView must be already created if filled the data.

Comment: I am at  BirthFragment and going to PeriodFragment. in BirthFragent include EditText for getting username of user, and i want save this data in sharedPrefrences.

Comment: Complete source for viewpager : https://www.dropbox.com/s/oba8ue1h35osh57/Viewpager1.rar

Comment: I solved it.. your problem was in initiating the fragment.. your creating new instance rather than using the same instance... and also I have change the function from 'onPageSelected' to 'onPageScrolled' read about it to understand what is going on... if you couldn't work it out yet i can send back the project fixed check the updated part again. and give me a feedback about it ;)

Comment: i changed code to onpageScrolled But Not work..Please give me correct answer

Comment: alright here you go.. I changed some stuff in the layout and other things... but not major stuff at all.. you can easily track back here is the project: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/18078970/Viewpager1.rar happy prgoramming